# Showing positive Ricci curvature is preserved under the Ricci flow, why is this operator locally Lipschitz?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I understand that one must use the following tensor maximum principle in order to prove that positive Ricci curvature is preserved under the Ricci flow:

> $\textbf{The Tensor Maximum Principle.}$ Let $g(t)$ be a smooth $1$-parameter family of Riemannian metrics on a closed manifold $\mathcal{M}^n$. Let $\alpha(t) \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(T^{*}\mathcal{M}^n \otimes_{S} T^{*} \mathcal{M}^n)$ be a symmetric $(2, 0)$ tensor satisfying the semilinear heat equation: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\alpha \geq \Delta_{g(t)} \alpha + \beta$$ where $\beta(\alpha, g, t)$ is a symmetric $(2, 0)$ tensor which is locally Lipschitiz in all its arguments and satisfies the $\textbf{null eigenvector assumption}$ that $$\beta(V, V)(x, t) = (\beta_{ij} V^{i} V^{j})(x, t) \geq 0$$ whenever $V(x, t)$ is a null eigenvector of $\alpha(t)$, that is, whenever $$(\alpha_{ij} V^{j})(x, t) = 0$$ If $\alpha(0) \geq 0$ (that is, if $\alpha(0)$ is positive semidefinite), then $\alpha(t) \geq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$ such that the solution exists.

Now, on the books I'm reading, the proof of that fact (the preservation of positive Ricci curvature under the Ricci flow, not the tensor maximum principle) goes like this:

> Since $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} R_{jk} = \Delta R_{jk} -Q_{jk}$$
> where $$ Q_{jk} = -3 R R_{j k}+6 g^{p q} R_{j p} R_{q k}-\left(2|\mathrm{Ric}|^{2}-R^{2}\right) g_{j k}$$
> And since at any point and time where the Ricci tensor has a null eigenvector, it has at most two non-zero eigenvalues, whence $|\text{Rc}|^2 \geq \frac{R^2}{2}$, the desired result follows immediately from the tensor maximum principle.

The thing is, I'm having trouble seeing why a particular hypothesis in the tensor maximum principle holds true here (namely, the locally Lipschitz one - the null eigenvector assumption is clearly satisfied). Of course, $\text{Ric}_{g(t)}$ must play the role of $\alpha$ and $Q$ the one of $\beta$.

**But why is it that $Q$ is locally Lipschitz?**

I assume that given a $(2, 0)$ tensor $T$, then $Q(T)$ would be given by $$(Q(T))_{jk}= - 3\text{tr}(T)T_{jk} + 6 g^{pq}T_{jp}T_{qk} - 2(|T|^2 - \text{tr}(T)^2)g_{jk}$$

I found this pretty hard to answer, but all the books I've read don't even address it so it must probably be something obvious... however I can't see how on Earth this is true. I would greatly appreciate it if someone clarified this issue for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $Q$ is a polynomial (when considered as a function of $\mathrm{Rc},g,t$), so it's locally Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought about it that way. So, to be clear, $Q$ *does not* take tensors as its input? It just depends on the (time-dependent) metric? If so I see how my doubt is really silly.

Comment: Made a typo in my last comment but should be fixed now @AnthonyCarapetis. I had thought this could be it but didn't think that would do be enough since it would be too easy

Comment: it does take tensors as input. Think of it as a map from symmetric matrices to symmetric matrices. There's a little bit of subtlety involved in formalizing this (you need to assume some kind of isometry invariance if you actually want to apply a function of matrices to a tensor field without being frame-dependent), but the important point is that $\def\R{\mathrm{Rc}}|Q(\R_1) - Q(\R_2)| \le C |\R_1 - \R_2|$ locally.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis It's a little more clear now, but let me see if I'm understanding this correctly: it does take tensors as input, but only Ricci tensors from different instants in time, right? Not just any $(2,0)$-tensors?

Comment: I'll check it now that you mentioned it, thanks for the tip and the help!

Comment: We happen to be plugging in the Ricci tensor, but if you want to view this as showing that a function $\beta$ is locally Lipschitz, you should think of it as a function of an arbitrary 2-tensor/matrix.

Comment: Huh... then I guess my remarks in the question were right. I'll try some more to see if this operator being a polynomial in the tensor we're plugging in becomes more clear. Thanks again! @AnthonyCarapetis